Is there a node package or service that is built for receiving emails and using a webhook to trigger events?
I am looking for a service or package that I can setup so that when I forward an email to a certain email address (lets say ticket@example.com) that email can monitor the mailbox of that email and trigger a webhook with the specific details of that email (sender, subject, body, etc)
My primary use case is when I get an email from a customer and I see that it might be a possible sale I would like to forward it to that email to start a AI workflow (seeing conversion detail, do research, create ticket, etc)
I have seen some node services such as nodemailer and other ones where you essentially setup and expose a webserver (which I am trying to avoid if possible) I would love a service like resend that is just for recieving emails.
